# Nesting method calls in java

Tags: java

This is my code:

```
public class Test{
    public static void main (String []a){
    int x = 3;
    System.out.println(fact(x));
    System.out.println(fact(4));
    System.out.println(fact(fact(3)));
}
public static int fact(int n){
    int f=1;
    for(int i=1; i<=n;++i)
        f = f*i;
    return f;
 }
}
```

the Output is:

```
6
24
720
```

My question is how on the **third print** statement, did we get `720`?

Comment: factorial of 3 equals to 6 (3! = 6), if the 6 is passed to fact() method it will be 6! = 720 ?

Comment: Becuase the `fact(3)` = 6  and the `fact(6)` = 720

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fact(fact(3))` means to get the the return of the function `fact(3)` and use it as argument again in another call to `fact`.

Split it up to understand it better. `fact(fact(3))` means the same as:

```
int value = fact(3);
fact(value);
```

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly related to programming, anyway I'll tell you:

```
fact(fact(3)) = fact(3*2*1) = 6! = 6*5*4*3*2*1 = 720
```

Answer (score 2):

This is only a math problem.

```
3! = 3x2x1 = 6
(3!)! = (3x2x1)! = 6! = 6x5x4x3x2x1 = 720
```

What were you exactly expecting ?

Answer (score 1):

fact(fact(3) : factorial of factorial

first you need to solve inner factorial i.e. fact(3) = 3*2*1 = 6

Now outer fact(6) = 6*5*4*3*2*1 = 720

hope this helps.